# possible loss of precision using doubles in a switch case

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm wrtiing a class for a resistor and I want to give a number for tolerance and it spit back out the color of the band for that tolerance value. I've used this same exact method with the other int values, but this double one doesn't work and I can't figure out why. Can anyone help please. I've already tried putting 'd' at the end of all the case numbers to make sure they were doubles, that did not fix it so that can't be the issue.

```
  public static String toleranceColor(double tolerance)
 {
  String band1 = null;
  switch (tolerance)
 {
  case 1: band1 = "BROWN"; break;
  case 2: band1 = "RED"; break;
  case 0.5: band1 = "GREEN"; break;
  case 0.25: band1 = "BLUE"; break;
  case 0.1: band1 = "VIOLET"; break;
  case 0.05: band1 = "GREY"; break;
  case 5: band1 = "GOLD"; break;
  case 10: band1 = "SILVER"; break;
  case 20: band1 = "NONE"; break;
  default: band1 = "INVALID TOLERANCE"; break;
 }
}
```

Comment: You can't use `double` values with a `switch`.

Comment: From the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html): A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer

Comment: Why dont you just multiply per 1000 so that you can "round" your double in int?

Comment: This is crying out to be refactored as an enum, but exactly what the design looks like depends on how it's being used, which isn't shown.

Comment: Floating point values are not exact.  You should never try to test equality (as in a switch statement).  Test for ranges instead.

Comment: @stark - that really only applies if you try to do arithmetic with doubles.  There's no arithmetic going on here, so the comparison is fine.

Comment: these are enum values, but this method is to return the enum name as a string given the variable. thank you piacente.cristian. i will multiply by 1000 and then divide again after the switch to make it a double

Comment: @David Wallace You don't know how tolerance is generated.

Comment: user3282440 - Why divide again?  You don't need to "keep" the multiplied value - see Dinesh's solution.  Just be extremely careful of errors that arise from floating point precision.

Comment: @stark - what you say is true.  But if the program introduces an error by doing arithmetic somewhere else, that's not the fault of this method here.  I took OP's phrase "I want to give a number for tolerance" to mean that it was just directly input, rather than calculated.  In my experience, the best way to avoid problems associated with floating point is to understand really well what `double` and `float` _can_ and _can't_ do, and only use them appropriately.

Comment: @DavidWallace The program isn't "introducing an error" when it calculates a floating point value that doesn't exactly match a constant.  One of the things that you can't do with floating point is test for equality, unless you know that both values are generated in exactly the same way.  Without that knowledge, testing for equality is an error in this program.

Comment: @stark Strongly disagree.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to use `double` with your `switch` case. `switch` should only be used for problems with discrete values, consider using an enum as a replacement or multiplying the value by 100 and converting it to an `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `double` numbers to integers and get the same solution. You cannot use `double` with switch.

```
 public static String toleranceColor(double tolerance)
 {


 String band1 = null;
 switch ((int)(tolerance*100))
 {
  case 100: band1 = "BROWN"; break;
  case 200: band1 = "RED"; break;
  case 50: band1 = "GREEN"; break;
  case 25: band1 = "BLUE"; break;
  case 10: band1 = "VIOLET"; break;
  case 5: band1 = "GREY"; break;
  case 500: band1 = "GOLD"; break;
  case 1000: band1 = "SILVER"; break;
  case 2000: band1 = "NONE"; break;
  default: band1 = "INVALID TOLERANCE"; break;
 }
}
```

Comment: This happens to work with these particular values.  But in general, doing arithmetic with a `double` and then casting to an `int` is a very good way to turn "floating point precision" into an "off-by-one error".  If you _have_ to do things this way (and you absolutely don't, because there are other solutions), please make sure you test it _very_ carefully.  This solution can _not_ generally be used with different numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Build a `HashMap<Double,String>` to store all the values, and populate it.  A static initialiser would be a good place to do this, since you're never going to change it and you only want to do it once.

Then, instead of the `case` statement, just use the map's `get` method.